# Capture Heroku SIGTERM in Celery workers to shutdown worker gracefully

Tags: python, heroku, rabbitmq, celery, sigterm

I've done a ton of research on this, and I'm surprised I haven't found a good answer to this yet anywhere.

I'm running a large application on Heroku, and I have certain celery tasks that run for a very long time processing, and at the end of the task save a result. Every time I redeploy on Heroku, it sends SIGTERM (and eventually, SIGKILL) and kills my running worker.  I'm trying to find a way for the worker instance to shut itself down gracefully and re-queue itself for processing later so that eventually we can save the required result instead of losing the queued task.

I cannot find a way that works to have the worker listen for SIGTERM properly.  The closest I've gotten, which works when running `python manage.py celeryd` directly but **NOT** when emulating Heroku using foreman, is the following:

```
@app.task(bind=True, max_retries=1)
def slow(self, x):
    try:
        for x in range(100):
            print 'x: ' + unicode(x)
            time.sleep(10)
    except exceptions.MaxRetriesExceededError:
        logger.error('whoa')
    except (exceptions.WorkerShutdown, exceptions.WorkerTerminate) as exc:
        logger.error(u'retrying, ' + unicode(exc))
        raise self.retry(exc=exc, countdown=10)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit) as exc:
        print 'retrying'
        raise self.retry(exc=exc, countdown=10)
    else:
        return x
    finally:
        logger.info('task ended!')
```

When I start this celery task running within foreman and hit Ctrl+C, the following happens:

```
^CSIGINT received
22:20:59 system   | sending SIGTERM to all processes
22:20:59 web.1    | exited with code 0
22:21:04 system   | sending SIGKILL to all processes
Killed: 9
```

So it's clear that none of the celery exceptions, nor the `KeyboardInterrupt` or `SystemExit` exceptions I've seen in other posts, properly catch SIGTERM and shut down the worker.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html?highlight=sigkill#process-signals seems to indicate that the main worker will always intercept SIGTERM.

Comment: Right--so is there any way to have the main worker propagate it to the children?

Comment: This is a problem which I have also never found a great solution. I tend to handle it in application logic by making sure my tasks are idempotent and tracking started and completed tasks such that I can automatically restart a given task when my application starts.

Comment: Has anyone solved this already? I'm also trying to find a solution for this - I need to correctly stop running tasks before deployment, so that they're either finished completely or rescheduled for after the deployment restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in version >= 4, Celery comes with a special feature, just for Heroku, that supports this functionality out of the box:

```
$ REMAP_SIGTERM=SIGQUIT celery -A proj worker -l info
```

source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/celery-heroku#using-remap_sigterm

Answer (score 1):

celery was unfortunately not designed to do clean shutdown. EVER. I mean it. celery workers respond to SIGTERM but if a task is incomplete, the worker processes will wait to finish the task and only then exit. In which case, you can send it SIGKILL if the workers don't shut down in a reasonable time but there will be a loss of information in this case i.e. you may not know which jobs remained incomplete.

Comment: As you can persist the task result, therefore it should be feasible to check on task status etc. at the application layer and recover the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [acks_late](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.acks_late) or [task_acks_late](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_acks_late).

Tasks will be acknowledged from queue **after** task finished execution and not just before. So task will respawn if worker shutdown gracefully.

Comment: just out of curiosity, how does the broker (say.. rabbitmq) distinguish between an anacknowledged message (task) because:
a) the task is still being processed
b) the worker died, it should be re-delivered